# Check for bootstrap-5 without jQuery

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I need to check if bootstrap-5 JavaScript file is loaded. There is a simple way of doing it using jQuery. For example, a common `asp-fallback` test expression for using Bootstrap JavaScript file from CDN is as follows:

```
asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.fn && window.jQuery.fn.modal"
```

Since older versions of Bootstrap JavaScript files relied on jQuery for their own operation, the above test worked well. However, [Bootstrap 5 is designed to be used without jQuery](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/), so a test that relies on `window.jQuery` is no longer appropriate.

What is a minimal expression that returns a truthy value only when one of the Bootstrap-5 JavaScript files is loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check `window.bootstrap` to verify Bootstrap 5 is loaded.

Comment: No, window.bootstrap initialized in BS4 as well as in BS5. Maybe you need to check window.bootstrap.Offcanvas, but IMO it's not reliable either.

Comment: I think the question is not how to differentiate between BS4&BS5, buth rather how to detect bootsrap (any version) is loaded now that jquery is no longer used.